# Return only Active Projects using Basecamp's API?

Tags: ruby, basecamp

Is there a way to return only active projects using Basecamp's API? No matter what I try I always get back my entire list of projects, and it's HUGE.

Here's what I think should work:

```
Basecamp.establish_connection!('myhost.basecamphq.com', 'my_user', 'my_pass')
@projects = Basecamp::Project.find(:all, params => { :status => 'active' } )
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's not. Best you could do is something like:

```
Basecamp::Project.find(:all).reject{|p| p.status == "archived" }
```

And from what I can gather from the API documentation, there's no way to do it.